# Winforms Bindingsource Datamember property interface displays nothing

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

> Setup:

- Class `Model` with one property which type is an interface.
- Create an instance and add it to a winforms bindingsource
- Add a textbox to winforms and configure the text value to use the bindingsource with the property as a datamember

> Model

```
public class Model
{
    public ICustomer Customer { get; set; }
}

public class Customer : ICustomer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}

public interface ICustomer
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

> Binding

```
this.textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this.bsModel, "Customer", true));
```

> Problem

When I run this code, the textbox remains empty (instead of showing the name of the customer).

BUT it does show it when I change the type of the Customer property in Model to the concrete Customer type.

I can't find any reason on MSDN why this is? Any ideas?

(Preferably no workaround like storing the toString value into another property, there is a framework doing this binding where I prefer not to hack into)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [`formattingEnabled`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.formattingenabled(v=vs.110).aspx) property to `false` fixes it so it uses the `toString()` method as in the concrete implementation.

```
this.textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this.bsModel, "Customer", false));
```

#### Problem:

I just browsed through the [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Binding.cs,c2cf415f45dded88) at msdn and bumped into the following line:

```
if (e.Value != null && (e.Value.GetType().IsSubclassOf(type) || e.Value.GetType() == type || e.Value is System.DBNull))
    return e.Value;
```

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The IsSubclassOf method cannot be used to determine whether an interface derives from another interface, or whether a class implements an interface.

So this will evaluate to `false` and the further conversion will end up in returning `null`.
By setting [`formattingEnabled`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.formattingenabled(v=vs.110).aspx) to false the parse method won't be called and the value will be simply returned instead.

Not sure if it's done on purpose or it's a bug. But I've got the feeling I better set the `formattingEnabled` to `false` for concrete types as well.

---

@Steve solution is working as well! (thanks) 
But he's working around the interface type.

I just prefer simply working with `toString()`, since it can change over time and it's much easier to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you should specify the property that should be binded to the Text property of the TextBox

```
this.textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding
              ("Text", this.bsModel, "Customer.Name", true));
```

If you remove the interface ICustomer and use directly the concrete class Customer then the binding code uses the ever present ToString() method that you have overridden in the concrete class and thus you get your textbox set.
For example, try to change the ToString to return a Surname property

Comment: Great, this works for name. But why can't it use the toString method when it's an interface. Since it's an instance the toString is always available somewhere? (I would still prefer a way with toString if possible, since it's already there on all classes that are to be displayed)

Comment: I found the underlying reason, although not sure if it's done on purpose. Thanks anyway.